# Why application works in AWS ElasticBeanStalk, after deleting war file from BeanStalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After deleting war file from BeanStalk, application still works in AWS ElasticBeanStalk.

I tried deleting war file from AWS S3, still it works. 
Doesn't tomcat undeploys war file, when we delete the version from "Application Versions" of Elastic BeanStalk?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds correct, deleting the version or the war file should have no impact on the copy running on the servers. You can deploy any application version to Beanstalk environments, but there is no "undeploy" command. You could remove the files directly in the instances or use Tomcat management APIs to achieve undeployments if you must.

Comment: 1) "You could remove the files directly in the instances " - How to do that?
2) " use Tomcat management APIs to achieve undeployments if you must." - Are you referring to the AWS SDK API http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html  ? I couldn't find the Tomcat management API to achieve undeployment?

Comment: 1) You could use EC2 System Manager (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/) or plain old SSH for running commands in your instances. 2) No, that would be Tomcat Manager (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html) and JMX